# There is an error in compilerconfig.json file. This could be due to a change in the format after this extension was updated

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, web-compiler

I use WebCompiler tool for Visual Studio 2017. But I am starting to get an error. This Error Message is:"
There is an error in compilerconfig.json file. This could be due to a change in the format after this extension was updated".

I thought the error originated from the file. I created new project and I do a test. But it didn't work. I got the same error again. My compilerconfig file:

```
[
  {
    "outputFile": "assets/scss/test-page.css",
    "inputFile": "assets/scss/test-page.scss"
  }
]
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKQMb.png)

Comment: What version of Web Compiler do you have? What kind of project is it?

Comment: Webcompiler version is 1.11.326. It is MVC web project (.NET Framework)

Comment: For future devs who might see this: Go to VS extensions and try just uninstalling and reinstalling WebCompiler. Worked for me, probably just some cache or temp file error.